# Face Generation TensorFlow increase size from 28px conv2d_transpose

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, generative-adversarial-network

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/HACKERSHUBH/Face-Genaration-using-Generative-Adversarial-Network/blob/master/face_gen.ipynb) and can successfully generate 28px sized faces using my GPU. However I do not know how to increase the size of the face (currently 28px) with the logic of the generator function below:

```
def generator(z, out_channel_dim, is_train=True, alpha=0.2, keep_prob=0.5):
    with tf.variable_scope('generator', reuse=(not is_train)):
        # First fully connected layer, 4x4x1024
        fc = tf.layers.dense(z, 4 * 4 * 1024, use_bias=False)
        fc = tf.reshape(fc, (-1, 4, 4, 1024))
        bn0 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(fc, training=is_train)
        lrelu0 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn0, bn0)
        drop0 = tf.layers.dropout(lrelu0, keep_prob, training=is_train)

        # Deconvolution, 7x7x512
        conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(drop0, 512, 4, 1, 'valid', use_bias=False)
        bn1 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv1, training=is_train)
        lrelu1 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn1, bn1)
        drop1 = tf.layers.dropout(lrelu1, keep_prob, training=is_train)

        # Deconvolution, 14x14x256
        conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(drop1, 256, 5, 2, 'same', use_bias=False)
        bn2 = tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv2, training=is_train)
        lrelu2 = tf.maximum(alpha * bn2, bn2)
        drop2 = tf.layers.dropout(lrelu2, keep_prob, training=is_train)

        # Output layer, 28x28xn
        logits = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(drop2, out_channel_dim, 5, 2, 'same')

        out = tf.tanh(logits)

        return out
```

I assume I will need to change something in the line of:

```
conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(drop1, 256, 5, 2, 'same', use_bias=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The change should be made on the last layer `logits` since that is the layer which determine the size of the output. changing `out_channel_dim` value to the size you want will be the solution. This may cause some error (due to the kernel size and stride values) or the result will not be the same (since your network is not trained for this size).